# Why didn't the Hogwarts ghosts know about the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, ghost

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146902/how-many-people-knew-the-chamber-of-secrets-existed) got me to wonder why Hogwarts ghosts never knew about the Chamber of Secrets.

Some [ghosts](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-ghosts) have been around Hogwarts for centuries. Plenty of time to explore the school grounds, talk to people who might know, or talk to the person killed by the basilisk. *"So the last thing you saw was a big pair of glowing yellow eyes over there by the sink? Well, Nick, let's float down through the floor by the sink and see what's there."*

They can move through walls, so they can access the [Chamber of Secrets](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/chamber-of-secrets) without needing to say "Open" in a Parseltongue.

They are immune to or less affected by hexes and charms that would bedevil living residents.

They had many opportunities over the centuries and the means to do it. **Why didn't the ghosts discover the Chamber of Secrets?**

Please support your answers with quotes from canon sources.

Comment: how do we know they didn't? In any case, not many characters really believed it existed in the first place (see Prof Binns comments in the book)

Comment: You get the impression that nobody really talked to Myrtle, living or ghost. I doubt any of the ghosts ever asked her how she died or connected her death with the Chamber of Secrets.

Comment: @TheDarkLord I'd find it strange if **not one** ghost was even mildly curious as to how Myrtle just suddenly went from healthy teen girl to dead in one second. Seems like strange magic is afoot.

Comment: @NKCampbell We don't know that they did not know, but if even one ghost knew, then certainly he/she/it could have mentioned something to the HeadMaster. *"Hey, Dumbledore, you wouldn't believe what I found beneath the girls' room!"*

Comment: I don't think most of the ghosts had much contact with students (though I might be wrong). Nick was the exception. Mostly they swooshed around and kept to themselves. Myrtle also lived in her toilet, away from the main communal areas.

Comment: I'm not sure that HP ghosts are capable of taking initiative in the way you're suggesting.  They generally seem to be kind of self-centered.

Comment: Don't forget **if they *had* found the glowing eyes, they would have been petrified.**  Under the lake.  So they wouldn't have come back or been treated.  Perhaps there *are* petrified ghosts in the Chamber.  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard I doubt they would have seen glowing eyes. The basilisk was hidden inside a separate part of the Chamber behind the face of Salazar Slytherin. As long as they don't go in there, they can get back. What they would do is go back and tell the Headmaster about the parts of the Chamber they did find.

Comment: No time to do a proper answer, perhaps someone can flesh this out: Ghosts exist when magical folk die with strong unresolved desires, resentments, or unfinished business.  They don't change, and in fact after death do not learn or grow, thus they may resent something that happened centuries ago - they cannot let it go because they themselves cannot change.  If they were not interested in exploring sewers in life, they would not be interested in doing so in death.  If they didn't chase down every rumor they heard in life, they wouldn't in death.  http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost

Comment: @AdamDavis The ghost of Crowthar the Curious did indeed find the chamber of secrets.  Of course, we've never heard of him because he never came back.

Comment: @AdamDavis That would make a good answer. Can you rewrite your comment into an answer with quotes from the books?

Comment: @TheDarkLord According to this site, close to one-thousand years after Helena Ravenclaw's death, she still maintained her intellectual curiosity. http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Helena_Ravenclaw And she preferred out of the way secluded places. Just the kind of ghost who would go looking for the Chamber of Secrets.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The Chamber of Secrets was described as being far below the school. Likely deeper than the dungeons:

> **It was like rushing down an endless, slimy, dark slide. He could see more pipes branching off in all directions**, but none as large as theirs, which twisted and turned, sloping steeply downwards, **and he knew that he was falling deeper below the school than even the dungeons**. Behind him he could hear Ron, thudding slightly at the curves.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets: Chapter 16, The Chamber of Secrets</sub>

> **"We must be miles under the school**,’ said Harry, his voice echoing in the black tunnel.
>   ‘Under the lake, probably,’ said Ron, squinting around at the dark, slimy walls.
>   <sub>ibid.</sub>

It's possible while going between the walls and floors the ghosts may have seen pipes, but they have no reason to follow all the pipes. They likely just assume their all some sort of plumbing or other ordinary things that were added in.

Comment: Maybe ghosts have a limited area where they can exist and so the chamber was out of their scope. Still I guess that someone could have talked with Myrtle about her death in the last 50 years already...

Comment: Hmm I believe that's discussed in another question, but what would she have said? "I saw to big yellow eyes?" Ghost/interrogater "*Hmm that's interesting, don't know what that is. Maybe she just killed herself cuz she kept getting bullied*"

Answer (score 14):

If a ghost did go hunting for the Chamber of Secret of his own accord it too might have been petrified.

> It was Nearly Headless Nick, no longer pearly-white and transparent,
>   but black and smokey, floating immobile and horizontal, six inches off
>   the floor.
>
> -Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter Eleven (The Dueling Club).

This might explain why a ghost might not come back trying to find the chamber if it did go looking for it.

As suggested by Skooba,  a lack of a ghost returning might tell you something that is dangerous down there, but what it is you might not be able to determine as the ghost would be unable to tell you, being ghost petrified as such.

Comment: But if ghosts sent to find something specific stopped coming back, wouldn't that alert the staff something was amiss and a more thorough search was needed?

Comment: @Skooba I guess i was thinking that a ghost just went of his own accord, If sent I guess there are other things that can hurt a ghost.

Comment: @Skooba: It's probably more presumed the ghost got taken down in the Forbidden Forest, rather than petrified in a hidden chamber with a pair of glowing yellow eyes. Or that they were presumed to have ended up in the Shrieking Shack nearby. ["When you hear hoofs, think horse, not zebra."](https://datasmart.ash.harvard.edu/news/article/when-you-hear-hooves-think-horse-not-zebra-1079)

Answer (score -5):

The ghosts of Hogwarts are described as ghosts, and some of them interact with the living as though they are alive.

However, they're not alive and assuming they're just like living people who can also float/walk through walls/etc is an error on the part of the reader.

The house ghosts may exist in an disconnected state where they are not aware of the world around them, and assuming they experience time in the same way as the living is unproved.

**TL;DR** the **eerie-fairies** are a bit **airy-fairy** and not really aware of the living world around them.

Comment: Moaning Myrtle, Nearly Headless Nick, Professor Binns, and Helena Ravenclaw all interacted with living breathing people. They all demonstrated awareness of events in the living world. Do you have any quotes from the book which specifically say ghosts are not aware of the world around them?